# Connecting to postgres using Docker container-Django

Tags: python-3.x, postgresql, django-rest-framework, docker-compose

## It's been hours I spent on, but unable to connect to postgresql with Docker container.  It is generating below error "password authentication failed", Please explain where I went off the line and help me. Thank you in advance.

Docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3"
services:
  app:
    build:
      context: .
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    volumes:
      - ./app:/app
    command: >
     sh -c "python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000"
    environment:
    - DB_HOST=db
    - DB_NAME=app
    - DB_USER=postgres
    - DB_PASS=supersecretpassword
    depends_on:
    - db

  db:
    image: postgres:13-alpine
    environment:
    - POSTGRES_DB=app
    - POSTGRES_USER=app
    - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=supersecretpassword
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.8-alpine
MAINTAINER Leo Developers Ltd

ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

COPY ./requirements.txt /requirements.txt
RUN apk add --update --no-cache postgresql-client
RUN apk add --update --no-cache --virtual .tmp-build-deps \
      gcc libc-dev linux-headers postgresql-dev
RUN pip install -r /requirements.txt
RUN apk del .tmp-build-deps

RUN mkdir /app
WORKDIR /app
COPY ./app /app

RUN adduser -D user
USER user

settings.py

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'HOST': os.environ.get('DB_HOST'),
        'NAME': os.environ.get('DB_NAME'),
        'USER': os.environ.get('DB_USER'),
        'PASSWORD': os.environ.get('DB_PASS'),
    }
}
```

ERROR:

```
$ docker-compose up    
db_1   | 2020-08-16 16:48:26.478 UTC [27] FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "postgres"
db_1   | 2020-08-16 16:48:26.478 UTC [27] DETAIL:  Role "postgres" does not exist.
db_1   | Connection matched pg_hba.conf line 99: "host all all all md5"
app_1  | psycopg2.OperationalError: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "postgres"
    app_1  | django.db.utils.OperationalError: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "postgres".
```

Comment: I'm not a docker user, but shouldn't your DB_USER agree with your POSTGRES_USER?

Comment: Both should the same?

Comment: Of course, else how you want it to be able to connect?

Comment: Can you explain clearly? Sorry I am missing something

Comment: In your docker-compose.yml your `POSTGRES_USER`should be `postgres`and not `app`.

Comment: Removed all existing containers by using "docker-compose down" and changed POSTGRES_USER=postgres, and did "docker-compose up" and connected to the database.